# Self-signed root certificate doesn't work on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, code-signing

I've created self-signed CA-certificate and added it to "trusted root certification authorities".
Then I've created another certificate that was signed by created earlier CA-certificate.
Then I've signed my exe with first certificate, download this file on the computer and try to launch. But Windows thinks that it is untrusted file. In the file properties I can see digital sign with my certificates' hierarchy.

So, the question is what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @jww: he's trying to sign an executable he wrote, so this is on-topic here IMO.  And I don't see how Web Apps or Webmaster could be relevant?

Comment: Thanks @Harry. I parsed it incorrectly. Good luck with it.